# AngularJS : How do i override directive's style in my view?

Tags: angularjs, html, css, angular-directive

I am calling `error-stuff` directive in my view as below and i am trying to override the directive's padding 15px to 0px in my view which is not working. So my div1's value and div2's values are not in a straight line since div2 takes more padding in my view.

```
 Error:
          Oops !!! Its look like something going wrong !!! Please try again later ...


<div id="div1" class="row">
   <div  class="pull-left">
      <span>Error :</span>
   </div>

    <div id="div2" style="padding:0px; vertical-align:top">
        <error-stuff></error-stuff>
    </div>
</div>
```

The html template on the `error-stuff` directive as below

```
<div class="error-class">
   <span>Oops !!! Its look like something going wrong !!! Please try again later 
    ...  </span>
</div>
```

**in my app.css**

```
.error-class
{
margin-bottom:20px;
padding:15px;
box-sizing:border-box;
line-height:1.5;
font-size:15px;
}
```

So how do i make **div1 and div2 content in straight line** by overriding the directives padding:15px to padding:0px?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `error-stuff` is used somewhere else and you can't change the global css, in this case you can use a targeted override by specifying the parent in css

```
#div2 .error-class {
    padding: 0;
}
```